# Calculate vegetation area for the years back (1982 1992, 2002, 2012 and 2022) in Google Earth Engine

Tags: google-earth-engine

How can I calculate vegetation area for the years back (1982 1992, 2002, 2012 and 2022) in Google Earth Engine? I run the following code for 2012:

```js
// Load the data and select the bands of interest.
var gfc2014 = ee.Image('UMD/hansen/global_forest_change_2015');
var lossImage = gfc2014.select(['loss']);
var gainImage = gfc2014.select(['gain']);

// Use the and() method to create the lossAndGain image.
var gainAndLoss = gainImage.and(lossImage);

// Show the loss and gain image.
Map.addLayer(gainAndLoss.updateMask(gainAndLoss),
    {palette: 'FF00FF'}, 'Gain and Loss');
    
// Displaying forest, loss, gain, and pixels where both loss and gain occur.
var gfc2014 = ee.Image('UMD/hansen/global_forest_change_2015');
var lossImage = gfc2014.select(['loss']);
var gainImage = gfc2014.select(['gain']);
var treeCover = gfc2014.select(['treecover2000']);

// Use the and() method to create the lossAndGain image.
var gainAndLoss = gainImage.and(lossImage);

// Add the tree cover layer in green.
Map.addLayer(treeCover.updateMask(treeCover),
    {palette: ['000000', '00FF00'], max: 100}, 'Forest Cover');

// Add the loss layer in red.
Map.addLayer(lossImage.updateMask(lossImage),
    {palette: ['FF0000']}, 'Loss');

// Add the gain layer in blue.
Map.addLayer(gainImage.updateMask(gainImage),
    {palette: ['0000FF']}, 'Gain');

// Show the loss and gain image.
Map.addLayer(gainAndLoss.updateMask(gainAndLoss),
    {palette: 'FF00FF'}, 'Gain and Loss');
    
var PAs = ee.FeatureCollection("WCMC/WDPA/current/polygons")
var PA = PAs.filter(ee.Filter.eq('WDPAID',1105));
Map.addLayer(PAs,['green'],'ChizariraNP');
//Map.centerObject(PA, 10);


// Get the forest loss image.
var gfc2014 = ee.Image('UMD/hansen/global_forest_change_2015');
var lossImage = gfc2014.select(['loss']);

// Sum the values of forest loss pixels in the ChizariraNP.
var stats = lossImage.reduceRegion({
  reducer: ee.Reducer.sum(),
  geometry: ChizariraNP,
  scale: 30,
  maxPixels: 1e9
});
print(stats);

print('pixels representing loss: ', stats.get('loss'));

// Subset the ChizariaNP feature from PAs.
var ChizariraNP = ee.Feature(
  PAs
    .filter(ee.Filter.eq('PAs_na', 'Rep of the ChizariraNP'))
    .first()
);

// Subset protected areas to the bounds of the ChizariraNP feature
// and other criteria. Clip to the intersection with ChizariraNP.
var protectedAreas = ee.FeatureCollection('WCMC/WDPA/current/polygons')
  .filter(ee.Filter.and(
    ee.Filter.bounds(ChizariraNP.geometry()),
    ee.Filter.neq('IUCN_CAT', 'VI'),
    ee.Filter.neq('STATUS', 'proposed'),
    ee.Filter.lt('STATUS_YR', 2012)
  ))
  .map(function(feat){
    return ChizariraNP.intersection(feat);
  });

// Get the loss image.
var gfc2014 = ee.Image('UMD/hansen/global_forest_change_2015');
var lossIn2012 = gfc2014.select(['lossyear']).eq(12);
var areaImage = lossIn2012.multiply(ee.Image.pixelArea());

// Calculate the area of loss pixels in the ChizariraNP.
var stats = areaImage.reduceRegion({
  reducer: ee.Reducer.sum(),
  geometry: PAs.geometry(),
  scale: 30,
  maxPixels: 1e9
});
print(
  'Area lost in the ChizariraNP:',
  stats.get('lossyear'),
  'square meters'
);

// Calculate the area of loss pixels in the protected areas.
var stats = areaImage.reduceRegion({
  reducer: ee.Reducer.sum(),
  geometry: PA.polygon(),
  scale: 30,
  maxPixels: 1e9
});
print(
  'Area lost in protected areas:',
  stats.get('lossyear'),
  'square meters'
);
```

Unfortunately, I am receiving this error
[image]

```
Area lost in the Chizarira NP:
ComputedObject(Error)
  User memory limit exceeded.
```

and

```
Line 103: PA.polygon is not a function
```

Comment: Error messages should always be added as text in the body of the Question. This assures that it is legible on all devices, and searchable as well.

Comment: @Vince If the link code and assets are available, error messages pop up immediately. However, ChizariraNP and PAs geometries (I guess for Zimbabwe) are not accessible (however, I got the last error message).

Comment: @xunilk If the text is not in the body of the Question, then others will not be able to find it. Not having the way to find the Question devalues any possible Answer.

Comment: Thank you, I am recieving the following errors: first: ComputedObject (Error)
User memory limit exceeded. and second: Line 104: PAs.polygon is not a function.

Comment: Your script Is not useful because layers above mentioned are not available.

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of problems with the script.

- You're using `ChizariraNP` before you defined it, causing `reduceRegion()` to run on the footprint of `lossImage`. You're essentially summing up all the pixels for the whole world at 30m scale. That will fail.
- `ChizariraNP` is a feature, not a geometry. When passing it as a geometry in `reduceRegion()`, you need to do `ChizariraNP`.geometry()`.
- `ee.Filter.eq('PAs_na', 'Rep of the ChizariraNP')` doesn't match any elements. There is no `PAs_na` property in the dataset.
- You're running `reduceRegion()` on `PAs`, which is a feature collection with `100,000+` features. That will fail.
- `PA` is a feature and have no `polygon()` method. You should use `geometry()`.

You should try to start with a simpler script, and get that running. Then add functionality bit by bit, while still keeping it running.